# Eclipse IDE & Import issues

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat5.5

Lately I have been trying my hands on Eclipse IDE for java development. I am mostly a novice to java programming. I am trying a servlet project, using Tomcat5.5 as container. I am getting issues when I give `import javax.servlet.*` statement in my class files, as Eclipse complains that it cannot find that particular package. I am working in windows environment, and have already included following on my classpath:

```
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_07\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\common\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\common\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\common\lib
```

Any ideas, as what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One last thing: that `CLASSPATH` value you posted looks suspiciously like a Windows system environment variable value.  You need to know that every IDE and Java EE app server out there, including Eclipse and Tomcat, completely ignores CLASSPATH environment values.  It's best to know how to set `CLASSPATH` appropriately for your situation.  I don't have a `CLASSPATH` environment setting on any machine that I work on.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this...yes, it actually is environment variable value. Pardon me for my lack of knowledge on this issue,...but just so that I correctly comprehend what you are saying: is that the value we set in classpath env. variable does not get used by any IDEs or j2ee servers, so we separately need to modify CLASSPATHS for each project??...

Comment: Of course, because every project is different.  Each IDE has their own was of setting CLASSPATH.  Java EE app servers have conventions that you're expected to follow.  It's not nearly as big a problem as you're making it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

Add a lib folder to the project and put in required jars.
Then right-click on each jar and add to build-path.